# Nginx - Angular not passing Authorization header

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, angular

This is the schematic of my microservices setup:

[image]

To put in words:

1. request comes from browser
2. nginx reverses proxy the request to the angular container
3. angular container makes request to the backend service to retrieve data

Now my backend service is protected and can be accessed only with an Authorization header which is generated in the backend itself when hitting /login.

[image]

If the login is successful, angular will take the token and attach it to every subsequent request to the server. Only that it doesn't happen.

[image]

As you can see the Authorization header is not embedded into the request therefore the backend service will never receive it and throwing a 401.

This is my angular nginx full setup:

```
server {
  listen 4200;

  location / {
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;

    proxy_pass_header       Authorization;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;


  }

}
```

whilst this is the nginx reverse proxy

```
    location /myne-dashboard-webui/ {
       proxy_pass http://myne-dashboard-webui/;
       proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
       proxy_pass_header       Authorization;
    }
```

I have tried to use proxy_pass_header, set_header $http_request and add_header, but all failed. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance

Edit: Furthermore, if I run my angular application and the backend standalone, wo without nginx and docker then it works as expected, so I rule out the possibility that one of my services are wrong
[image]

Comment: Why are you looking at nginx? The problem seems to be in your frontend.

Comment: Hey @MichaelHampton I'm not sure about that because if I run it in my local it works as expected

Comment: You show it not working on localhost! And nginx has nothing to do with your frontend code anyway.

Comment: Hey @MichaelHampton, this is all inside nginx and docker. If I run my angular app and my server separately without the help of nginx or docker it will run fine. Thus my hypothesis that somehow nginx is not behaving properly

Comment: @MichaelHampton to convince you, I tested and edited the question with a screenshot of the request working as expected outside of nginx and docker